# Reading input from .exe and writing to a .exe for reading Chess engine commands

Tags: c++, pipe, exe, interaction

I am searching all day for an example c++ program which will use ready .exe file which has as an output strings and then waits for standart input and again prints outputs and so on and so forth.

For example my c++ program will use standard output to write "uci" to a .exe program, the .exe program will reply with a string again which I will be able to read in my c++ program and again I will send a new string and will wait for a reply by the .exe.

I found something about pipes but I thought they were really difficult to understand.Is there any ready library/interface I could use? Or any example you can give me with pipes?

Comment: An example of Named pipes can be found here: http://avid-insight.co.uk/2012/03/introduction-to-win32-named-pipes-cpp/  and shared memory  found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You are talking about inter-process communication. The current C++ standard acknowledges only multiple threads, not processes. So you need more than just C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open to use bigger frameworks, there is an easy to use class in Qt to handle processes: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html.

```
QProcess exe;
exe.start("foo.exe");
exe.write("uci");
exe.waitForReadyRead();
auto result = exe.readAll();
```

On windows you can use CreateProcess/CreatePipe, but the code will be a lot more verbose. Example:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Hmm your example seems exactly as easy as I need.So when you call waitForReadyRead() your program waits for a reply by the foo.exe program right?And after that when you call exe.readAll() you get the string that foo.exe produced after you sent it the uci command/?

Comment: Yes, waitForReadyRead() blocks until new data can be read from foo.exe, than readAll() reads all available data.

Comment: great! do I need to include the whole Qt library to my project?

Comment: I mean can I just use the include Qt libraries just like opencv with lib files etc?

Comment: It is not header only. You have to link your app with Qt5Core library.

Comment: ok thank you very much.I will try it right now and let you know if this was the correct answer.Although if it works as you said,it is exactly what I wanted

Comment: Could you please tell me which libraries should I include? I mean do I need every single qt lib or not?

Comment: You should include QProcess header, then link libQt5Core.

Comment: I only see qprocess.h though(I am in VS 2010)

Comment: in the qt folder include folder and specifically in the qtcore there are headers but also there are common Files with not extension.QProcess is one of them

Comment: QProcess file should be next to qprocess.h. There is no .h extention after QProcess.

Comment: You can convert the result to std::string: QString(result).toStdString()

Comment: yes I managed to include it.
 When I run exe.waitForReadyRead(); I get qobject starttimer qtimer can only be used with threads started with qthread as a return string. Do you know why?

Comment: Although after this, I do get the required string

Comment: No. It works fine on linux. Altought Qt classes usually used from Qt applications (using QApplication class).

Comment: Oh that is too bad,but i do get the string ;)
I hope to find some solution to it

Answer (score 2):

If you just know basics of c++ may be you should follow this as it does not require any external libs, though some say system is evil, its okay if it doesn't go to production level programs

```
int main()
{
   std::string in;
   while(std::cin >> in)
   {
      std::string cmd = std::string("/full/path/to/second.exe <") + in + " >outfile.txt";
      system(cmd.c_str());
      std::ifstream fin("outfile.txt");
      std::cout << fin;
   }   
}
```

Comment: nice example.However I want the program to respond without closing at all.For example:

user types: uci
.exe program replies: "string"
user types: ucinewgame
.exe replies : ready

and so on and so forth.So user keeps adding new strings in the .exe program and continues after each new string

Comment: I want to send strings in the .exe after it has started and during the whole duration

Comment: you'll be launching uci.exe separately? are you writing uci.exe or is it an external program?

Comment: we have one program called engine.exe. I want to open that program through my cpp program and then pass strings to it and receive strings that come out of it(engine.exe)